# Power BI Deneb Edge Bundling visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, deneb

I'm trying to re-create this visual in Power BI with Deneb,  my input data is similar to the sample from https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/edge-bundling/

What should I update in the code to change data sources to xlsx on my PC?

Because in the sample it refers to  "url": "data/flare-dependencies.json", "data/flare.json"

Thanks in advance!

I was trying to change the "url": "data/flare-dependencies.json", "data/flare.json" as path on my PC.

Comment: I suggest working through the docs on the main website to better understand how it works. https://deneb-viz.github.io/

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks for your response. I have checked the documentation, there is not much information regarding connection of other data sources for already existing templates.

Comment: What you're referring to isn't a Deneb template - it is simply a Vega spec. I suggest starting with some simple Deneb charts to get the hang of things before trying the edge-bundling example as that one is at the complicated end of the spectrum.